# understanding requirejs paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Using requirejs my main.js looks like this

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/javascript/',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min',
        async: 'requirePlugins/async',
            hbs: 'hbs'
    },
    waitSeconds: 7
});
define(['common'], function () {
    loadFonts();
});
```

The main.js is included in the page with a script call

```
<script data-main="/javascript/main.js" src="/javascript/require-2.0.1.js"></script>
```

Common is the basic function for the website, jquery doc ready function etc. wrapped in a define call:

```
define(['jquery'], function() {
    //jQuery dependant common code
});
```

This works fine, jQuery is loaded from the google CDN and the code is executed. But when i add a require call after the load of main.js

```
<script data-main="/javascript/main.js" src="/javascript/require-2.0.1.js"></script>
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    //code
});
```

jquery is requested from /javascript/jquery.js instead of the defined path to the google cdn. I'm still a rookie at requirejs but it would seem to me that the path should be defined before any of the other requests are fired, can somebody please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I think this could be due to using the `data-main` attribute on the RequireJS script tag; for that to be parsed, RequireJS itself has to load and parse. In my testing (specifically for IE9), the browser would download and execute any script tags directly following the RequireJS script tag before parsing the RequireJS config file (the one specified by the `data-main` attribute).

To get around this, I simply quit using the `data-main` attribute and instead placed the config file as a normal script tag directly after the RequireJS script tag, and everything seems to be happy now.

Specifically, this is what it looks like (using your sample):

```
<script src="/javascript/require-2.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: After wasting over an hour on this I gave up on `data-main` as well. Using the two script approach eliminated my define loading errors.  TYVM!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you put the config statement before require js being loaded.

You should load require.js first, put your config code after, then call require(['jquery'], ...);

The reason it searches /javascript/ is because your require.js file is located there and it is the default base url.

Your config may never be used by require.js.

See [this tutorial](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) about require config.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename define to require

```
require(['common'], function () {
    loadFonts();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`map`](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) instead of `paths` to configure specific module locations.

`paths` is intended more for shortcuts/prefixs to simplify/configure includes, rather than full module paths.

Bear in mind: you'll need to place mappings you want to apply globally under an asterisk (`*`) key in the `map` object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you put `require(['jquery']...` immediately after loading require.js module. As the result, it tries to load `['jquery']` before reading your config settings.

And why it tries to find jquery in `/javascript/jquery.js`? that is because of your `data-main` attribute.

> RequireJS loads all code relative to a baseUrl. The baseUrl is
>   normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main
>   attribute for the top level script to load for a page.

This link clarifies require.js module loading procedure:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Answer (score -2):

i think you can embed the full url in the require block. like:

```
require(['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min'], function ($) {
   //code
});
```

btw, your jquery link is invalid.

Comment: I could, but jQuery defines itself as a amd module so I should be able to use 'jquery' instead of having to write the entire url every time.

Why is the jquery link invalid?

Comment: hi, i tried to visit `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min` and found 404.

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot the requirejs appends .js to the script assuming all modules are scripts. your link is correct. sorry for confusing.