# RequireJS: Paths not working from require.config()

Tags: javascript, requirejs, config

Even though I include my `require-min.js` is included, it's not picking up my `paths` from `require.config`. I've used the `data-main` method to load the config file.

```
<!--when require.js loads it will inject another script tag
    (with async attribute) for scripts/main.js-->
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

> You will typically use a data-main script to set configuration options
>   and then load the first application module. [...]

However, the aliases I am using for jQuery don't work. In my **config.js** file...

```
...
 paths: {
        jQuery: 'ThirdParty/jquery-1.8.3.min'
...
```

My **index.html** is as follows...

```
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/require.js' data-main='js/config.js'></script>
...
require(['jQuery'], function ($) {
...
```

This throws up the following errors *sometimes* on **console**:

```
GET http://<IPADDRESS>/js/jQuery.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1895
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jQuery
```

I say sometimes since, say, 2 times out of 10 it loads properly. How do I solve this?

*Disclaimer: A closely related question is "[understanding requirejs paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895094/understanding-requirejs-paths)". However, the answer is not complete and does not come up as top hit for this specific question. Further, it's a reasonable copy-paste from the official docs. Mods please vote down as applicable. Oh, and edit this away as applicable also ;)*

Answer (score 8):

From the [official docs quoted above](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) and reading on:

> Note: the script tag require.js generates for your data-main module
>   includes the async attribute. This means that **you cannot assume that
>   the load and execution of your data-main script will finish prior to
>   other scripts referenced later in the same page.**

**Solution:**

Include the config file synchronously by using plain old `<script>` tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/require.js'>
<script src='js/config.js'></script>
```

This solves the issue.

---

**Additional Info**

[Docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)

> Also, you can define the config object as the global variable require
>   before require.js is loaded, and have the values applied
>   automatically. This example specifies some dependencies to load as
>   soon as require.js defines require():

```
<script>
    var require = {
        deps: ["some/module1", "my/module2", "a.js", "b.js"],
        callback: function(module1, module2) {
            //This function will be called when all the dependencies
            //listed above in deps are loaded. Note that this
            //function could be called before the page is loaded.
            //This callback is optional.
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```